# Combinatorics problem applied to GAM logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic, roc, generalized-additive-model, combinatorics

I'm doing biomedical research and I need to set a GAM Logistic Model which get the maximum AUC score as possible. I have 4 disease markers; $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, Y_4$ with different data in each one, and the model must have the following specification:

$\text{Model} = \log(\text{Odds Ratio} (\text{Illness}~|~Y_j,Y_i)) = \alpha + \sum\limits_{i,j}^n f_k(Y_k) $

The problem is that I need to code in R all the possible combinations between this 4 markers without repetitions, in order to do multiple comparisons, such as:

$\text{Model}_1 = \alpha + f_1(Y_1) + f_3(Y_3)$ or $\text{Model}_2 = \alpha + f_1(Y_1) + f_2(Y_2) + f_3(Y_3)$ etc.

When I code each model manually I use sentences like these. This is an example for a model with only one marker:

```
model=gam(group~s(y1),family='binomial')
pred=predict(model,type='response')
r=ROCEmpiric(group,1-pred)
```

Where `group` is always in, as indicator of disease, and `ROCEmpiric` is a function which calculates the ROC value.

Does anyone know the way to automate the calculations? It's seems ridiculous to write each function after doing the summation of permutations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me know if this works. This code loops through all combinations of $Y_{1}$ through $Y_{4}$ and saves `r` (AUC) and the combination each time. As I don't have the data, I'm not 100% sure if it does what you want.

```
combinations <- list(
combn(1:4, 1),
combn(1:4, 2),
combn(1:4, 3),
combn(1:4, 4)
)

res.frame <- data.frame(r=numeric(), formula=character())

for( i in 1:4 ) {
  for( j in 1:dim(combinations[[i]])[2] ){

    form.temp <- as.formula(paste("group~", paste("s(y", combinations[[i]][,j], ")", sep="", collapse="+"), sep=""))

    mod <- gam(form.temp, family="binomial")
    pred <- predict(mod, type="response")
    r <- ROCEmpiric(group, 1- pred)

    temp.frame <- data.frame(r=r, formula=paste("group~", paste("s(y", combinations[[i]][,j],")",sep="", collapse="+"), sep=""))

    res.frame <- rbind(res.frame, temp.frame)

  }  
}
```

Comment: I've viewed the code just right now, so I'll test it as soon as possible (presumably this evening). Thank you very much.

Comment: @anxoestevez Could you look into the code? Did it work?

Comment: Yes, it worked very well. Sorry for the time to respond.

Comment: Of course! It was my fault to not answer you at the time, but I was ill for the past two months. I have now another open question, if you want to check it. Thanks :-)